# Remove the 'Press This' Tool

Tags: plugins, customization, dashboard

Is there anyway to remove the 'Press This' tool from WordPress for all users?

Thanks!

Comment: Define _remove_. Just remove the visible link or break its functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following action essentially disables the press-this functionality, at least best I can tell:

```
add_action('load-press-this.php', function(){ wp_die('"Press This" functionality has been disabled.'); });
```

The option will still be there on the admin dashboard page, but attempting to use it will fail.

Answer (score -2):

Simplests way... Rename press-this.php in the wp-admin base directory. I changed mine to press-this.not. Still shows on the link page, but comes up as a missing page.

Comment: never ever ever modify core files in any way. this will most likely fail when you will upgrade to the next core version